# Jquery/Javascript How to change <meta property="og:title"> dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this `<meta property="og:title" content="some title">` in my `<head>`-section. I want to change this meta property depending on which page the user is navigating to. So first of all, in my index.html I have a default value in the `<head>`-section:

```
<head>
    <meta property="og:title" content="some title whatever">
</head>
```

then I wrote this script, which I keep in an external .js file:

```
function setMetaTag(metaName, name, value) {
        var meta = '<meta '+metaName+'="'+name+'" content="'+value+'"/>';
        $(meta).insertAfter('title');
}
```

then I do this on every subpage:

```
setMetaTag('property', 'og:title', 'new title for this page');
```

so far it works, but of course, when users click back and forth on the page the new `<meta>`-tag gets repeated x-times and when users go back on the index.html, the `<meta>` from the previous title is displayed and not the default value.

How can I achieve, that only the title gets displayed once and default value gets displayed when back on the index.html?

Comment: To avoid repetition, check if it exists before adding a new one: `$(meta).length == 0` means there's no element satisfying the selector.

Comment: If you want to change `og:title` so that Facebook will pick it up when a page is shared – that is of course pointless, because FB’s scraper tool does not execute client-side code.